# Social Sharing and Deep Linking - Ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, deep-linking, socialshare

[DEEPLINKS]
I would like to share on Facebook a deeplink of my app so the user that click on the link it's able to open the app (if already installed) in the page that the deeplink reference and the link on the store (if the app is not installed).

It's possible?

I've installed the Native Deeplink plugin and followed this tutorial https://ionicthemes.com/tutorials/about/ionic2-app-with-socialsharing-and-deeplinking but nothing works because the deeplink that I've shared it's passed like a string and it's not clickable.

I'm not able to find a recent documentation or tutorial, nothing that works so I have doubt that is it possibile to do it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: please check this https://docs.branch.io/pages/apps/cordova-phonegap-ionic/

Comment: also interested in this. Is your app a hybrid or web app? I guess the former as you mentioned the need for user to go to a store if they dont have the app?

Comment: @SergeyRudenko it's an Hybrid app built with Ionic v3.

Comment: @AnandhSp I'll check the link. thank you.

Comment: Found similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/51985914/4005366

Comment: @SergeyRudenko thank you, but the issue that you have linked it's still open without answers...

Comment: Yes i meant there is gotta be common problem. Nit that its a dupe;)